# MySQL Updating duplicate records

Tags: mysql

I'm not even sure this is possible in a query, but here goes.  I'm cleaning up data coming into our system from a 3rd party.  They're creating a not-so-unique unique string for each person in a group that consists of the first 3 letters of the first name and then the dob in yyyymmdd format.  On the few that are duplicates, I want to append -1, -2, -3 etc. to that ID so they truly are unique.

```
JOH19700101     0001    JOHN SMITH    1970-01-01
JOH19700101     0001    JOHNSON SMITH 1970-01-01
JOH19700101     0002    JOHN SMITH    1970-01-01
```

In the above, the first two IDs (JOH19700101) need to have -1 and -2 appended because they are in the same group (0001).  The 3rd can remain the same as he's in a different group (0002).

Selecting the duplicates was easy enough:

```
SELECT x.id, x.uid, x.group, x.name, x.dob
FROM import x
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT uid
    FROM import
    GROUP BY group, uid
    HAVING COUNT(uid) > 1) z ON x.uid = z.uid;
```

Is there a way to add an update to this so that the first two samples would get new UIDs of JOH19700101-1 and JOH19700101-2 respectively?

Comment: Something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998877/row-number-by-several-columns  using variables., and then it's an update based on values on the whole row.

Comment: Do you want to run the update in a rolling manner, as in append (-1,-2,-3) as it goes through and finds duplicates? You will need a procedure then, to keep track of the duplicate count for each unique ID.

Comment: I am thinking triggers here. Just a hint

Comment: You could insert them all into a temp table w/ auto-incrementing id, then grab this:

SELECT t.id, t.grp, count(*) cnt
FROM <your_temp_table>
GROUP BY id, grp

And then as you're inserting into your target table, if the cnt is 1, insert as is, else insert (uid + auto-inc-id). I wonder if you wouldn't be better off just putting an auto-incrementing id on your target table, and letting the uid be duped?

Comment: Triggers would work for new data, but not for the existing dataset. Unless that's not an issue, then triggers all the way. Before inserting a record, just check to see if the ID duplicated and how many times. If so, append the appropriate suffix to the "id" column, and insert away.

Comment: I provided an answer, but it seems you lost interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you unique uid values although it could benefit from one small refinement. Right now the number that is appended keeps incrementing, so your first pair of dupes will get -1 and -2 appended to their uids, then the next pair -3 and -4, and so on.

It should be possible to reset @inc somehow, however as it stands this will ensure that all of your uid values are unique, and that identical uids in different groups will remain unchanged.

```
SET @inc :=0;

UPDATE 
 `import` i
       JOIN (
   SELECT uid, `group`
   FROM `import`
      GROUP BY `group`, uid
   HAVING COUNT(uid) > 1) d ON 
  i.uid = d.uid AND 
  i.group = d.group

SET
  i.uid = CONCAT(i.uid, '-',@inc:=@inc+1)
```

Comment: By the way I put your import table name and group column name in smart quotes as the names conflict with MySQL functions - and in some GUIs such as sqlyog, this will play havoc with the formatting and result in illegal syntax.

Comment: Sorry - was on vacation with no email.

Comment: No worries! Hope the solution is still useful